# Show that the found value is the MLE

Tags: statistical-inference, estimation

Let $ X_1, ... X_n$ i.i.d with pdf

$$f(x;\theta)=\frac{x+1}{\theta(\theta+1)}\exp(-x/\theta), x>0, \theta >0$$

It is asked to find the MLE estimator for $\theta.$

The likelihood function is given by

$$L(\theta;x)=[\theta(1-\theta)]^{-n}\exp\left(-\frac{\sum_i x_i}{\theta}\right)\prod_i (x_i+1)I_{(0,\infty)}(x_i)$$

Then, the derivative of log-likelihood will be

$$\frac{dlogL(\theta;x)}{d\theta}=\frac{-(2\theta+1)n}{\theta(1+\theta)} + \frac{\sum X_i}{\theta^2}$$

I've obtained my candidate to MLE. But, doing the second derivative of the log-likelihood, I could not conclude that it is negative so that the candidate is, indeed, the point of maximum. What should I do, in this case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Basically, increase/decrease the second derivative by epsilon and see what happens.

Comment: I didnt understand your approach.

Comment: You have your second derivative, call it $g(\theta)$. It has the value A at your estimate. Evaluate it at $g(\theta + \epsilon$). Let $\epsilon$ approach zero, first from above, then from below. Are those bigger/smaller than A?

Comment: Well, since the MLE candidate and the second derivative do not have a good form, I dont think this is a a good way.

Comment: So what is the second derivative?

Comment: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+%28d%2Fdx++%281%2F%28x%281%2Bx%29%29%5Enexp%7B-1%2Fx%7D%29%29+>+0&x=0&y=0 , x is $\theta$ and $a=\sum x_i$

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the form in that.